# How to animate only selected items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have `RecyclerView` and I want to animate one `View` inside `RecyclerView` item only for items which meet certain condition.

I'm using `ObjectAnimator` for this. Sometimes it is working fine, but sometimes animation is applied to all views. I assume there is some recycling problem with `Views`, but I'm not certain what can cause that.

Example:

```
val halfHeightCropped = halfHeight - (stopIndicatorHeight/2) //half item height minus half timeline circle height
        val halfDistCurrToNext = timeDistCurrToNext/2
        if (alreadyTraveled > halfDistCurrToNext){
            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(indicator, "translationY",  halfHeightCropped.toFloat()).apply {
                duration = 0
                start()
            }
        }
```

I'm an animating circle that is moving vertically through a timeline based on real-time. This circle is part of each `RecyclerView` item and in some items, this item is stationarily centered in item `View`, and some (1 at the time) is animating this circle vertically.

The example above is part of the function which is called from `onBindViewHolder` if the item meets the condition, otherwise, the view is reset to a default position. (layout param center vertical in an item).

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell without more context, but are you canceling your animations on binding another item to the viewholder?

Answer (score 0):

when item select from recyclerView select that into adapter like

```
yourAdapter = new yourAdapter(new ArrayLis(),new ItemOnClick(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(int position){
        yourAdapter.selectItem(position)
    }
});
```

perform animate in bind() method of *holder* class.

```
if(selectedItem = getAdapterPosition){
    //perform your animation for the selected item
}
```

your adapter should have the selectedItem variable and setter method for that.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, `ArrayLis` isn't a thing and neither is `bind()`

Comment: this is just an example, you can replace your adapter.